# H1 inside div cancels jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with jQuery animations, I have 5 boxed on a page, on every box there is a hover handler that extends the box and shows some extra text. In every box there is h1 tag with some text. That h1 tag is there to begin with (no hover) and stays there when you hover, the problem is when I hover over the h1 tag the animation stops and the box retracts to original state (like no hover)

Here is the jsfidle, just hover over the box, and then the word 'why' (the h1) to see what is the problem. I would like that the box stays extended even when I hover over h1. Thank you

HTML:

```
 <div class="box">
        <h1>why</h1>
        <div>
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .box{
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 320px;
    margin: 0 155px 40px 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.box > div {
    display: inline-block;
    width:280px;
    height:280px;
    padding:20px;
}

.box > div p{
   color: #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: 28px;
    width: 450px;
}

.box h1{
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 32%;
    font-family: 'DeftoneStylus';
}

.box:nth-child(1) > div{
    background-color:red;   
}

.box:nth-child(1) > div:hover{
    background-color:blue;
}

.box:nth-child(1):hover h1{
    color:#94C11F;    
}
```

jquery:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.box > div').hover(function() {
        $(this).clearQueue().parent().css('z-index', '10000')
        $(this).clearQueue().find("p").css('display', 'block')
        $(this).animate({
            width: 785, height: 280, margin: 0,
        });
    }, function() {
        $(this).clearQueue().parent().css('z-index', '100')
        $(this).clearQueue().find("p").css('display', 'none')
        $(this).animate({
            width: 280, height: 280, margin: 0,
        }, function() {
            $(this).parent().css('z-index', '0');
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bfxem/

Comment: Because you're saying `$('.box > div')` which is the direct descendant selector. In your HTML the `h1` tag is not inside `$('.box > div')`

Comment: As @NickR is saying, the h1 is not inside the div, so even if you're putting its height to zero, it's always a block element, so if you hover its area, there will be no bound event to it. You can keep it there but with a smaller z-index then the div, for example.

Comment: If I add z-index:-1 to h1 then it is hidden behind. Can I somehow add a jquery selector that says count in h1 also?

Comment: You can definitely add a selector in there to account for the h1 tag. It's as simple as changing `$('.box > div')` to `$('.box > div, .box > h1')`. You'll have to then account for $(this) not necessarily being the div element though. http://jsfiddle.net/Bfxem/10/

Also, the answer below from @Olaf works as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move `h1` inside the `div` and `position: absolute`

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div>
        <h1>why</h1>
        <p>Our purpose, our difference. We are a ...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box h1 {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 32%;
    left: 30%;
}
```

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bfxem/7/)

Comment: Ty, I don`t know how I did not thought about this. One more question, why when I change the jquery handler to click this whole thing does not work?

Comment: What do you mean with this? When I add `$('.box > div').click(...)` it works perfect, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bfxem/11/). Do you have a JSFiddle or something?

Comment: [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) has only *one* function parameter. When you give it two parameters, the first one is data and the second one is the handler function.